# How can I display all the error message from the register using useEffect in react hook form

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form

What I want to do is display all the error message as long as the page loads using useEffect. Then I have a 3 error messages that will be displayed if the input is focused beside these text theres an icon “check” and “x” if the validation is met it is “check” then if its not its “x”. Heres a reference for what I want to achieve. Thanks for your help. https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_password_val

````
            register(e, {
              minLength: {
                value: 8,
                message: "atleast 8 numbers",
              },
              pattern: {
                value: "mypattern",
                message: "must have 1 number",
              },
              maxLength: {
                value: 20,
                message: "error message",
              },
            });
            inputRef.current = e;
          }}```
````

Answer (score 0):

If you want to see all errors message associated with particular input then you should set `criteriaMode` to `all`, so it will show all the errors with the input.

> criteriaMode  firstError | all When set to firstError (default), only
> the first error from each field will be gathered.
>
> When set to all, all errors from each field will be gathered.